# Labelling graph over an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory

[image: Have a look]

I was reading about this equivalence of [labellings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_labeling) on a graph where they mentioned about a group equivalence as a product of an automorphism with a labelling. I don't understand what kind of product is this? I am unable to prove this an equivalence relation using the ordinary product of maps.